# Is it possible to beat level 20 of the Mine without any damage?

Tags: sanctum

I downloaded Sanctum on Steam tonight. I was able to get through the first 19 levels of the Mine without the shield taking any damage, but I've now tried 4 times on level 20 and I can never take down the Big Walker. Is it possible or is he just there to absorb damage?

I have several laser towers upgraded to level 5 and I freeze him twice in their area (he has to pass them twice). I'm also critting him with the sniper rifle constantly, but I never even get close to taking him out.

Any tricks or tactics would be much appreciated, but I'd also just like to know if it's possible at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is certainly possible, I don't know his health but you can take him down with fully maxxed weapons and judicious use of the switched-out-weapons-still-reload trick.

Check out the end of the following [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HhoVm-jHaRs&NR=1) for a demonstration.  (The final wave starts around 42:40.)

Comment: Thanks for the link. It's been awhile since I accepted the answer, but in case the link goes down... the method used was to constantly slow the mobs while constantly walking backwards from in front. Slow-Grenade-Sniper-Sniper-Repeat. It took me a little while to get used to navigating the whole maze backwards.

Comment: Yes, I guess your original idea was in the right direction.